# How to ensure an insert() has propagated to all members of a replica set

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having a problem retrieving documents from a MongoDB collection immediately after inserting them. I'm creating documents, then running a query (that cannot be determined in advance) to get a subset of all documents in the collection. The problem is that some or all of the documents I inserted aren't included in the results.

The process is:

1. Find the timestamp of the most recent record
2. Find transactions that have taken place since that time
3. Generate records for those transactions and `insert()` each one (this can and will become a single bulk insert)
4. `find()` some of the records

The documents are always written successfully, but more often than not the new documents aren't included when I run the `find()`. They are available after a few seconds.

I believe the new documents haven't propagated to all members of the replica set by the time I try to retrieve them, though I am suspicious that this may not be the case as I'm using the same connection to `insert()` and `find()`.

I believe this can be solved with a write concern, but I'm not sure what value to specify to ensure that the documents have propagated to all members of the replica set, or at least the member that will be used for the `find()` operation if it's possible to know that in advance.

I don't want to hard code the total number of members, as this will break when another member is added. It doesn't matter if the `insert()` operations are slow.

Comment: @Kelvin You shouldn't wait until it has propagated to all members. Instead make sure you read to the server you've written to (primary).

Comment: Can you show your code? Also, can you clarify how you are connecting to your instance? You are reading from the primary, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Read preference

When you write to a collection, it's a good practice to set the [`readPreference`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) to "primary" to make sure you're reading from the same MongoDB server that you've written to.

You do that with the [`MongoCollection::setReadPreference()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.setreadpreference.php) method.

```
$db->mycollection->setReadPreference(MongoClient::RP_PRIMARY);
$db->mycollection->insert(['foo' => 'bar']);
$result = $db->mycollection->find([]);
```

---

#### Write concern (don't do it!)

You might be tempted to use [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/) to wait for the data to be replicated to all secondaries by using `w=3` (for a 3 server setup). However this is not the way to go.

One of the nice things about MongoDB replication, is that is will do automatic fail over. In that case you might have less than 3 servers that can accept the data, cause your script to wait for ever.

There is no `w=all` to write to all server that are up. Using such a write concern wouldn't be good. A secondary that have just recovered from a fail over might be hours behind, taking a long time to catch up. You script would wait (hang) until all secondaries are caught up.

A good practice is **never** to use `w=N` with `N > majority` outside of administrative tasks.

Comment: `setReadPreference()` looks like *exactly* what I need, but unfortunately it's not working as expected; the inserted records still aren't being returned. I'm running MongoDB 2.4, is it possible there was an issue in this version?
For some context, this *is* an administrative task, which is why I'm also not worried about the inserts taking a while.

Comment: 1) I don't believe this is the issue here, since read preferences aren't mentioned by the OP. 2) primary is the [default read preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#read-preference) so it doesn't need to be set. 3) what is wrong with [{w:majority}](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#modify-default-write-concern). This is a valid way to ensure that there are no rollbacks. I would agree that w > majority can be dangerous so consider a [wtimeout](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/#wtimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for a [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/), which (in Layman's term) allows you to specify when insert is finished.

In PHP this is done, by providing an [option in the insert statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php), so you need something like

> w=N   Replica Set Acknowledged    The write will be acknowledged by the primary server, and replicated to N-1 secondaries.

or if you do not want to hard code `N`:

> w=   Replica Set Tag Set Acknowledged    The write will be
>   acknowledged by members of the entire tag set

`$collection->insert($someDoc, ["w" => 3]);`

Comment: While hard coding the number of server works, you'd get a timeout if one of the secondaries is down.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels have I told that this is a good idea? The author explicitely asked to propagate to all members - and I showed him how to achieve it.

Comment: He also states that he doesn't want to hard code it. So N might be any number. When N is unknown at runtime, this method can't be used. Reading from master solves his problem, though in a different way than he proposes.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels so you mean that "w= Replica Set" is not the correct solution?

Comment: `w= Replica Set` doesn't exist. I thing you mean`w= <tag set>`. [Replicate Set Tag Sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/) is an advanced feature which you can use to specify a subset of servers. I doesn't really apply in this situation. To prevent reading stale data, read from the master. Write concern with N > majority shouldn't be used, unless you're 100% sure that your setup is 100% healthy.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys, all of this is really helpful. You're both right in that `w=N` could solve the problem, but it's not viable for my environment. Since `setReadPreference()` doesn't seem to be working for me, replica tag sets look like a strong solution.
I've added a tag to all members of my replica set: `{ "rs" : "all_members" }`, but after scouring the documentation I'm struggling to figure out the correct syntax for the insert. According to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/) `"w"="rs"` will write to at least one member, not all